# Update a table timestamp field when the record changes

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, absolute-db

I am using absolute database as my database. Since absolute database does not support triggers I have to write my own UPDATE trigger. I tried this way :

```
procedure TDataModule2.ABSQuery6AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  ABSQuery4.Close;
  ABSQuery4.SQL.Clear;
  ABSQuery4.SQL.Text :='UPDATE MYTABLE SET RECORDCHANGED=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';
  ABSQuery4.ExecSQL;
end;
```

But this way I am updating the entire table. How can I update only the record (row) that was changed ?

edit : This is how I made it work

```
procedure TDataModule2.ABSQuery6AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
with ABSQuery4 do begin
ABSQuery4.Close;
ABSQuery4.SQL.Clear;
ABSQuery4.SQL.Text :='UPDATE MYTABLE SET RECORDCHANGED=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE    T_ID=:a1';
ABSQuery4.Params.ParamByName('a1').AsInteger := ABSQuery6.FieldByName('T_ID').AsInteger;
ABSQuery4.ExecSQL;
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to your query a 'where' clause. The SQL becomes

```
update mytable
set recordchanged = current_timestamp
where id = id_of_last_changed_record
```

It's best to pass the id of the last changed record via a parameter, making your code

```
with ABSQuery4 do
 begin
  Close;
  SQL.Clear;
  SQL.Text :='UPDATE MYTABLE SET RECORDCHANGED=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE ID = :P1';
  sql.params[0].asinteger:= id_of_last_changed_record;
  ExecSQL;
 end;
```

Comment: Surely you know the id of the record that you have just updated. How did you update it without knowing its id?

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved very straight forward with the [`TDataSet.BeforePost`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.BeforePost) event (also have a look at the [code sample](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE4/en/BeforePost_%28Delphi%29) from docwiki)

```
procedure TDataModule2.ABSQuery6BeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  DataSet['RECORDCHANGED'] := now;
end;
```

Comment: +1, but note the problem that the server and client will not have their times synchronized. In fact the server may even be in a different timezone in which case the recorded time will make little sense.

Comment: @Sir Rufo - dataset not in insert mode. Putting it in insert mode and then calling post crashes the program.

Comment: Are you sure you have this method connected to `BeforePost` event? The documentation is clear this will be called before posting the data and for that the dataset has to be in insert or edit state. Maybe you have a bug inside of `TABSQuery`